# Spring service method validation

Tags: spring

I have a service class which is annotated with @Validated.
In this class I have a method with an argument which is annotated with @Valid.
If the method is called from another class instance with an argument that is not valid an exception is thrown.
As expected an error of type ConstraintViolationException is thrown.

If I call this method from another service method (internal call) no validation is performed and an error arises in the body of the method.
This is not what I want. Apparently calls made from within are not validated.
Investigating the problem I found out that the method was not invoked using a Spring proxy bean.
I fixed the problem by retrieving the proxy from the (@Autowired) application context and invoke the method using the proxy:

```
((T) context.getBean(this.getClass()).myMethod(validatedArgument)
```

This is an ugly solution.
How can I configure Spring so that method calls made from within are validated?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tricky way to autowire the service to itself.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Autowired
  private MyService copy;

  private void call() {
    //myMethod(validatedArgument);
    copy.myMethod(validatedArgument);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately Spring does not allow this.

Answer (score 0):

The way Spring handles aspects is such that they are only invoked when one instance sends a message to a different instance. There are some ways to overcome this, but in your case, the fact that you want to do it is probably revealing a design flaw.